# String allocation seg fault - why is this happening?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, reverse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Segmentation Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834032/getting-segmentation-fault)

```
/*  Reverse a string in place
 */
#import <stdio.h>

void reverse(char * str);

int main()
{
    char * string = "This is a string.";
    printf("%s\n", string);
    reverse(string);
    printf("%s\n", string);
}

void reverse(char * str)
{   
    char * start = str;
    char * end = str;
    if(0==*str)
        return;

    //Find the end
    for(;0 != *(++end););

    end--;
    do
    {
        *end   = *end ^ *start;
        *start = *end ^ *start;
        *end   = *end ^ *start;
    }while(++start < --end);
}
```

I'm not sure why this seg faults.  Is is because I'm initializing my char * with a constant string?

Comment: This is covered extensively in the question that this duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to modify a string constant. Replace:

```
char * string = "This is a string.";
```

with

```
char string[] = "This is a string.";
```

to remedy that.

Comment: Damn, I knew it was something stupid like that.