# GCC : Segmentation Fault from Trim function

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, segmentation-fault, trim

I got a gcc "Segmentation Fault" error with this script : http://paste2.org/p/1397204, why ?

I tested this code with Visual C++ compiler and I don't get any error...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Segmentation Fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834032/getting-segmentation-fault)

Comment: Can you help me to fix my code ?

Comment: Sure. instead of `printf("|%s|\n", trim("   MyStringHaveToBeTrimmed   "));`, do `char str[] = "   MyStringHaveToBeTrimmed   ";printf("|%s|\n", trim(str));`

Comment: And if you looked over my answer to case 1, you would have seen this fix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [MByD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464988/mbyd) according to [Getting Segmentation Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834032/getting-segmentation-fault) topic.

Replace :

```
printf("|%s|\n", trim("  MyStringHaveToBeTrimmed  "));
```

With :

```
char str[] = "  MyStringHaveToBeTrimmed  ";
printf("|%s|\n", trim(str));
```

New code : http://paste2.org/p/1397248

Comment: please mark it as accepted answer when you can, so people will know it's solved. In the meantime, add [solved] to the title of the question.

Comment: I got this box : "You can accept your own answer in 2 days", so I'll change question status as answered in 2 days...