# Why can I not pass a pointer to a char buffer to a function with param char**

Tags: c, pointers

If I have a function:

```
void myfunction(char** s);
```

Then I can pass a char* like this:

```
char* s = malloc(100);
myfunction(&s);
```

But my compiler won't allow me to do this:

```
char s[100] = {0};
myfunction(&s);
```

I thought that a pointer to the buffer should be allowed by the compiler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between char* and char** (in C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065277/difference-between-char-and-char-in-c)

Comment: Bo Persson - how is it a possible duplicate with that link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function expects a pointer to a *pointer* (`char **`). You are trying to pass a pointer to an *array* instead (`char (*)[100]`). Why do you expect this to "be allowed by the compiler"? Arrays are not pointers. Arrays and pointers are objects of completely different nature. A pointer to a pointer is not in any way compatible with a pointer to an array. You can't use them interchangeably.

If you want you use your array-based buffer with a function that expects `char **`, you have to explicitly create a pointer to that buffer first

```
char s[100] = {0};
char *ps = s;
```

and then pass a pointer to that pointer, as you did before

```
myfunction(&ps);
```

Comment: @Seçkin Savaşçı: Exactly. Arrays are not pointers. (Why is this confusion so persistent? There are like thousands explanations for that issue on SO, not even mentioning numerous FAQs on the Net) http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Comment: Arrays do decay to pointers at the slightest provocation, so it *is* odd that they don't in this occasion.

Comment: @bitmask Not really. The pointer to the first element in an array isn't *stored* anywhere. It's an rvalue. There is no position in memory for this `char**` to *point* to—the compiler doesn't store an array *and* a pointer to the first element in it. It just knows how to produce that pointer if necessary.

Comment: @bitmask: Any sort of decay is only possible in *value (Rvalue) contexts*. We are dealing an *object (Lvalue) context*, since we are taking the *address* of the array. It is not surprising that in *object contexts* any sort of decay is not applicable. You find it odd? Tell then, how would you implement the decay in this case? What would the `&` operator take the address of?

Comment: I assumed that the compiler would somehow save the address of the first element of the array (the buffer) and pass a pointer to this pointer.  I see now that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void myfunction(char* s[]){
    printf("Here: %s",s);
}
int main(){
    char s[100] = {'a'};
    //char s[100] = "myString";
    myfunction(&s);
}
```

This works on windows not sure on linux

Comment: This "works" because your compiler used very loose error checking and because your code contains, so to say, "even number of errors", which compensate for each other (2 errors). The first error is illegal call to `myfunction`: it expects `char **`, you supplied `char (*)[100]` instead. The second error is invalid call to `printf`: it expects `char *`, you supplied `char **` instead. Increase the error checking levels in your compiler and it should catch both errors (the first one at least). Try this http://comeaucomputing.com/tryitout in C mode to get more pedantic analysis of what you wrote.