# strcpy() causes segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, strcpy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Segmentation Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834032/getting-segmentation-fault)

Why does this code cause a segmentation fault?

```
char *text = "foo";
strcpy(text, "");
```

As far as I understand it, the first line allocates some memory (to hold the string "foo") and `text` points to that allocated memory. The second line copies an empty string into the location that `text` points to.

This code might not make a lot of sense, but why does it fail?

Comment: Look at the search results. LOOK AT THEM!@#! http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=strcpy+segmentation+fault

Comment: What is the best duplicate? I couldn't readily find it.

Comment: They're NOT all exact duplicates, but the mistake(s) are generally the same.

Comment: I agree John Kugelman. Moving to close for duplication.

Comment: @quasiverse: Before asking this question I saw that there are a lot of similar questions here on SO, but almost all of them are the other way around, namely declaring `char *text;` without allocating memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you have a string literal (in your case, "foo"), the program stores that value in a **readonly** section of memory.

`strcpy` wants to modify that value but it is readonly, hence the segmentation fault.

Also, `text` should be a `const char*`, not a `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Because a string literal (like `"foo"`) is **read-only**.

Answer (score 0):

Because the string literals are stored in the read only region of memory.

Thus attempting the modification of `foo`(using `strcpy` in this case) is an **undefined behavior**.